# Issue when running deploy static content command - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, static-content, static-content-deploy

When running the `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` command I am having an issue with the frontend of the site where it looks like it is loading the Magento/luma theme and ignoring all of my theme files.

Also, I have tried the `--exclude-theme` on the command to ignore the Magento/luma theme but no luck.

Here is how the website is looking when I run the command:

[image]

Comment: I have found a fix, Make sure the theme id is correct on the `core_config_data` table and `widget_instance` table in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another important thing is check your current theme from database in themes table. Your theme type should be physical.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot. There was an issue with the theme id parsed in the config and widgets table.

Comment: Yes it take 1 full day to find this issue source when I encountered first.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute this command you must add the languages ​​of your store and -f, for example my store uses Spanish from Spain so:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy es_ES en_US -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

I hope it helps